# When loading a csv file file how can insert negitive values as 0 and keep positive values

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

While reading over the docs I cannot seem to get this correct. I want to use load file to insert a CSV into a premade table. If one of the values is negative i want it to insert as 0. If not I want to keep its original value. I think im on the right track but i dont know.

```
ignore 1 lines (@item_name, @product_desc, @quanity_total) set item = @item_name, desc =     @product_desc, quanity = if(@quanity_total < 0 then 0 else @quanity_total);
```

Comment: set your table column type to unsigned and set it back once you are done importing

Comment: Two notes: the column name `desc` needs to be quoted with backticks and the syntax of [IF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) is different. I'm assuming you're using `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Comment: Correct VMai I am using load data infile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your LOAD DATA INFILE statement could be written as:

```
ignore 1 lines 
(@item_name, @product_desc, @quanity_total) 
set  item    = @item_name, 
     `desc`  = @product_desc,
     quanity = if(@quanity_total < 0,  0, @quanity_total);
```

or by removing two not needed variables as:

```
ignore 1 lines 
(item, `desc`, @quanity_total) 
set quanity = if(@quanity_total < 0,  0, @quanity_total);
```

The column name `desc` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) and got to be quoted with backticks.

The [IF syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) is as follows:

> IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)
>
> If expr1 is TRUE (expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL) then IF() returns
>   expr2; otherwise it returns expr3. IF() returns a numeric or string
>   value, depending on the context in which it is used.